# What are the rules for the plural suffix ～ら

Tags: nuances, suffixes, plurals

I came across the following in a newspaper article:

> 藤沢健太教授（宇宙物理学）らの研究グループ

The first part (藤沢健太教授) is the name of a professor (Professor Kenta Fujisawa). The parentheses say "Astrophysics", and the last part (の研究グループ) indicates his research group. It's the `～ら` that confuses me.

I had only ever heard `～ら` after `かれ` or `お前`, so I did some searching, and I found these sites.

- [This source](http://japanese.about.com/od/Grammar/a/Personal-Pronouns.htm) says it is used for `かれ`, but doesn't elaborate.
- [This source](http://thejapanesepage.com/w/index.php?title=Plurals) says that it is an informal version of　`～たち`, which doesn't seem to fit in the context of a newspaper (unless I'm wrong about that), or the very technical topic.
- And [this source](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Japanese/Grammar/Nouns) simply says that it's another version of `～たち`.

I'm still unclear as to when one should use ら if it's informal, yet also in the paper. Does anyone know　the nuance of it?

Comment: Besides whether they are correct or not, they don't conflict. What if ら can be used for かれ, and is another version of たち, namely, an informal version? Your question is strange.

Comment: @sawa I see what you're saying, but what I don't understand is why it's used in the newspaper, which as far as I know, doesn't use informal phrases. I re-read the first source...I misunderstood what it was trying to say, that ら　can be used for かれ, but it's not exclusive to it.

Comment: Although 俺ら is informal as claimed in your second link, I do not agree with the blanket claim that suffix ら is informal.  As you observed by yourself, use of suffix ら is common in the formal context such as newspaper articles.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pluralization in Japanese: usage of -たち and -ら](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1310/pluralization-in-japanese-usage-of-%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a1-and-%e3%82%89)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is rather the other way around of what the second link says, and the reason for that description is that it is probably confusing politeness and formality.

- ら: non-polite, formal
- たち: slightly polite, informal
- がた: polite

As for 俺ら, 俺 is highly informal, and the whole combination is informal because of that even if ら is formal.

And besides that, some personal pronouns only go with either of them as noted in the first link.