# How to do plurals?

Tags: pronouns, first-person-pronouns, plurals

I've seen there are two ways of saying **we** and pluralizing words using:

> ら、たち

But I can't see the difference and I'm not sure if it can be used with all the pronouns. Are there other forms of pluralizing words other than these. How should I use them and what's the difference.

Are all these forms right?:

> 僕たち・僕ら
>
> 俺たち・俺ら
>
> 私たち・私ら？
>
> 君たち・君ら
>
> あなたたち・あなたら
>
> 彼たち・彼ら
>
> 彼女たち・彼女ら
>
> 犬たち
>
> Etc.

What's the difference of using hiragana or kanji?

Comment: We have already two questions about this: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1310/pluralization-in-japanese-usage-of-%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A1-and-%E3%82%89 and http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15709/difference-between-%E5%83%95%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A1-and-%E5%83%95%E3%82%89

Comment: Before asking "how to do plurals?" it is also important to ask "when to do plurals?". You might be thinking that plurals express some meaning (more than one thing), and that this must be preserved when translating to Japanese. But a plural only means "more than one", it could 2,3,4,5,... - in that respect it's pretty unspecific. There are languages with a special form for 2 things (dual). In `There are many fruits on the table` the plural is redundant, `many` already specifies the amount.