# What is the meaning of らと?

Tags: meaning, plural-suffixes

I was reading this news article today:

[阿部サダヲが4年ぶりの主演ドラマで水原希子、山口智子**らと**共演](http://www.cinematoday.jp/page/N0070648)

In the heading and again in the text is 「山口智子**らと**共演」

My question is what is the meaning of the らと between Yamaguchi Tomoko and co-starring? I could not find any dictionary reference for it.

Comment: Related: [Pluralization in Japanese: usage of -たち and -ら](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1310/1628) and [Difference Between 僕たち and 僕ら?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15709/1628)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「らと」 is **two words**, not one, which is why it will not be found in the dictionary.

「～～ら」 = "~~, etc."

「と」 = "with"

> "Sadao Abe is co-starring ***with*** Kiko Mizuhara, Tomoko Yamaguchi, ***etc***."

Answer (score 4):

> = 達と

水原希子、山口智子**ら**と共演 → 水原希子、山口智子 **& Others**