# When to use the suffix "-tachi" and when to use "-ra"?

Tags: suffixes, plural-suffixes

"-Tachi" and "-Ra" for the apprentice seem to have the same usage. When do you have to use the suffix "-tachi" and when do you have to use "-ra"? Is one more formal than the other? Are there pronouns where you can use one but not the other?

Comment: oh, there it was. I looked for a question like that but I couldnt find it. Guess I had to type the hiragana characters

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/15740/9831 /