# Is たち in 子供たち redundant?

Tags: words, suffixes, plurals, plural-suffixes

In my understanding, 達{たち} is a suffix used to pluralize a countable noun. For example,

- 私 (single) becomes 私たち (plural)
- あなた (single) becomes あなたたち (plural)

According to most dictionaries, 子供  can be translated as either child or children. As a result, if we want to say children (instead of child), I think 子供 should be enough. In other words, is it true that for saying "children", たち in 子供たち is redundant?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pluralization in Japanese: usage of -たち and -ら](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1310/pluralization-in-japanese-usage-of-%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a1-and-%e3%82%89)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Japanese language doesn't have plural form of noun like English. So we can't know how many children are playing in the park in this sentence "子供が公園で遊んでいます".

If you want to say "A child is playing in the park", you say "一人の子供が公園で遊んでいます。"

If you want to say "Children are playing in the park", you say "子供たちが公園で遊んでいます。".

Answer (score 3):

No. I suppose it's a bit like `you guys`. It serves to make it clear there are multiple children.

Answer (score 1):

It is  explicit, to state that there are several children.

Comment: Sorry. It means that every countable noun in Japanese is implicitly plural, right?

Comment: @YasashiiEirian. sorry, I don't follow, what do you mean?

Comment: I meant for every countable noun in Japanese, there always exists both "singular" and "plural"
 meaning in it. Did  you think so?

Comment: @YasashiiEirian, Could you give an example of one of those nouns?

Comment: How about 子供 in question ?

Comment: @YasashiiEirian, If I am understanding you correctly, you are talking about the 「子」and「ども」making the plural, correct? And you are talking about similar type of nouns?

Comment: OK. Lets choose another word, for example, 本. Does it contain both "plural" and "singular" meaning?

Comment: @YasashiiEirian, with 「本」by itself it only contains singular meaning. However you could say this, 「あそこにある本を全部持ってきて」in this case this means bring me all the books from over there.