# The use of たち in the sentence

Tags: suffixes, plural-suffixes

Can  たち　mean "and the others"?

> メアリーさん**たち**はいつ神戸に行くつもりですか。

I know that  たち is a pluralizing suffix: 私たち、子供たち、etc. But I'm listening to 2 people talking about Mary *and her friends*. I am confused by how たち　is used here.

Comment: .... exactly as you just said it was being used.  Yes, it's a "pluralizer", but more flexible, and exactly as you said, can be used to mean "and the others". One point that should be noted is that it is assumed that the listener understands by context or familiarity, basically what "others" are being referenced.

This link may provide more context: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1310/pluralization-in-japanese-usage-of-%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a1-and-%e3%82%89

Answer (score 1):

It is some what similar to an English word 'lot', it's not a formal word to use, but it's not impolite either. 
'When are you lot going to Kobe?' is what it sounds like, but bit more polite than what English sounds.
If you want to be very frank and quite impolite you could use 「〜ら」, and in formal scenes 「〜方」.