# What is the difference between 'ぼくたち' and 'ぼくら'?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

What is the difference between 'ぼくたち' and 'ぼくら'? Both are written in kanji as 僕達 and mean 'we'. Are they equal in using?

Comment: If one writes the ら in 僕ら with Kanji, normally it's 僕等. My IME doesn't even have 僕達 as an option for 僕ら.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, they are written differently in kanji. ぼくたち is usually written as 僕たち (some dictionaries also list 僕達). ぼくら is written as 僕ら or 僕等.

Secondly, the difference in meaning and usage between ～たち and ～ら is answered in detail in a thread [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/8105/what-is-the-difference-in-usage-between-a-plural-using-a-the-kanji-repetition/8176#8176) and also [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1310/pluralization-in-japanese-usage-of-%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A1-and-%E3%82%89).